# How to configure Travis CI better for auto push to git branch?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, travis-ci, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

I'm developing a project at GitHub and using TravisCI. On GitHub, there's an option, which allows one to use one branch `gh-pages` to publish static web content online on `http://<user>.github.io/<repo>`.

As my project is a frontend one (WebGL/JavaScript) and doesn't require any backend, I decided to try the following deployment process:

1. Push to `master`, which will fire the CI service to build an application and run unit-tests.
2. If building and testing the app on Travis succeeds, then push the results to the `gh-pages` branch, where later the static content will be available in the following sub-directory:

   `/<commit#>.<build#>/<payload>` (e.g. `/925dc3e.4/index.html`)

The scheme itself is simple, but I'm afraid because of security reasons. I understand, that showing the password in some sort of a config file is a very bad idea. However, I've found the [encryption keys in Travis CI service](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encryption-keys) feature, but am not sure, whether it's secure enough, or insecure at all?

Comment: "Is it enough secure or insecure at all?" It's secure enough to use (the encryption is per-slug). I autodeploy to `gh-pages` myself on my project, you can see the `.travis.yml` [here](https://github.com/nabijaczleweli/BearLibTerminal.rs/blob/master/.travis.yml#L39-L49).

Comment: @набиячлэвэлиь thanks! it's great :)

Comment: How about using the `after_success` section instead?

Comment: @localheinz I pointed it out to him, in [the chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84081/loungegaem), later on